# Display information in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a database first model from my database and wrote the following code in the form load event:

This error is displayed when the form is opened:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
> index '

Code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace Automation
    {
        public partial class Kanoon : Form
        {
            public Kanoon()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void Kanoon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
            private void BindGrid()
            {
    
                using (KanoonEntities db = new KanoonEntities())
                {
                    gdPersons.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    gdPersons.DataSource = db.Persons.ToList();
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: gdPersons.Columns[0] <- while binding your gdPersons grid didn't have any column

Comment: If you are not defining your columns in the designer then you have no columns in the grid.

Comment: The database is local.
  How do I fix the error ??

Comment: You have options. I suggest you do some research, maybe [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-columns-in-the-datagrid-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: I defined the columns manually
And even automatically (by connecting to the dataset)

Comment: Please, don't change your code in a way that makes the question mute. You're referring to a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which now cannot be thrown, since the code that caused it is now missing. -- Clarify what you have set in the Designer, i.e., whether the `DataPropertyName` is set to the name of the Columns in the DataSource you're setting now. -- If you detach a DataSource set in the Designer, you lose the auto-generated Columns.

Comment: @JohnG That's what I wrote about. The OP changed the code. If you look at the revision history, you'll see: `gdPersons.Columns[0].Visible = true;`

Comment: The error is due to the datasource not containing any data.  So there are no rows in the source (rows = -1).  The db is empty unless the constructor is filling the KanoonEntities with data. : KanoonEntities db = new KanoonEntities()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BindingComplete`  event, which fires when all the databinding for the Gridview is finished, so you could access properties that are correctly binded at that time.
You need to set the attribute in your Initiallize and put the code in yours:

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

bindingSource1.BindingComplete +=
   new BindingCompleteEventHandler(bindingSource1_BindingComplete);
using (KanoonEntities db = new KanoonEntities())
{
    // Set the data source to the DataSet.
    bindingSource1.DataSource = db.Persons.ToList();

   // Add the control data bindings.
   gdPersons.DataSource = bindingSource1;

}
```

Then use the event:

```
private void bindingSource1_BindingComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

I tried to keep this generic, as is a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve with that visible = true;